# Android - Action Listeners for a list of dynamic buttons

Tags: android, dynamic, button, actionlistener

I currently have a listview where each row has a 'download' button but I cannot seem to be able to set the action listener for each button correctly. My code currently sets EVERY button to the same action..

```
List<MyListItemModel> myListModel = new ArrayList<MyListItemModel>();

....

MyListItemModel item = new MyListItemModel();
JSONObject e = catalogue.getJSONObject(i);
item.id = i;    
item.key = e.getString("key");      
bookKey = (e.getString("key"));  
item.setTitle(e.getString("title"));
item.setDescription(e.getString("description"));
// change the button action to the right download address 
item.listener = new OnClickListener(){
    public void  onClick  (View  v){
        downloadBook(bookKey);
    } 
};
```

I also have a MyListItemModel class which holds each book item AND a MyListAdapter with the following code for its getView method

```
 @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if(convertView==null){
        //convertView = renderer;
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.shelfrow, null);

    }
    MyListItemModel item = items.get(position);
    TextView label = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
    label.setText(item.getTitle());
    TextView label2 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_subtitle);
    label2.setText(item.getDescription());
    Button button = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_download);
    button.setOnClickListener(item.listener);
    return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
MyListItemModel item = new MyListItemModel();
JSONObject e = catalogue.getJSONObject(i);
item.id = i;    
item.key = e.getString("key");      
bookKey = (e.getString("key"));  
item.setTitle(e.getString("title"));
item.setDescription(e.getString("description"));
// change the button action to the right download address 
item.listener = new OnClickListener(){
    public void  onClick  (View  v){
        downloadBook(new String(bookKey));
    } 

};
```

Basically you've been passing a reference to the bookKey variable and so each time you change it it will change for each onClick Listener.

http://www.javacoffeebreak.com/articles/toptenerrors.html See number 6

Comment: thanks for this. I just now solved it by adding the listener in the MyListItemModelClass. I'll try your method now

Comment: I just tried your method and it still sets each button to the same book key :/